# Looking for tool to search text in files on command line

Tags: search, web, find

Hello 
 I'm looking some script or program that use keywords or pattern search in files ex. php, html, etc and show where is this file

I use command cat /home/* | grep "keyword"
 but i have too many folders and files and this command causes big uptime :/

I need this script to find fake websites (paypal, ebay, etc)

Answer (score 1):

```
find /home -exec grep -s "keyword" {} \; -print
```

Comment: I very much enjoyed your posts at dssheep.blogspot.com. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really say what OS (and shell) you are using. You might want to retag your question to help us out.

Because you mention `cat | ...` , I am assuming you are using a Unix/Linux variant, so here are some pointers for looking at files. (bmargulies solution is good too).

> I'm looking some script or program that use keywords or pattern search in files

`grep` is the basic program for searching files for text strings. Its usage is

```
grep [-options] 'search target' file1 file2 .... filen
```

(Note that 'search target' contains a space, if you don't surround spaces in your searchTarget with double or single quotes, you will have a minor error to debug.)

(Also note that 'search target' can use a wide range of wild-card characters, like .,?,+,*,.*, and many more, that is beyond the scope of your question). ... anyway ...

As I guess you have discovered, you can only cram so many files at a time into the comand-line, even when using wild-card filename expansion. Unix/linux almost always have a utiltiyt that can help with that,

```
startDir=/home
find ${startDir} -print | xargs grep -l 'Search Target'
```

This, as one person will be happy to remind you, will require further enhancements if your filenames contain whitespace characters or newlines.

---

The options available for grep can vary wildly based on which OS you are using. If you're lucky, you type the following to get the man page for your local grep.

```
man grep
```

If you don't have your page buffer setup for a large size, you might need to do

```
man grep | page
```

so you can see the top of the 'document'. Press any key to advance to the next page and when you are at the end of the document, the last key press returns you to the command prompt.

Some options that most greps have that might be useful to you are

```
-i (ignore case)
-l (list filenames only (where txt is found)
```

There is also fgrep, which is usually interpretted to mean 'file' grep
becuase you can give it a file of search targets to scan for, and is used like

```
fgrep [-other_options] -f srchTargetsFile file1 file2 ... filen
```

---

> I need this script to find fake websites (paypal, ebay, etc)

**Final solution**

you can make a srchFile like

paypal.fake.com
ebay.fake.com
etc.fake.com

and then combined with above, run the following

```
startDir=/home
find ${startDir} -print | xargs fgrep -il -f srchFile
```

Some greps require that the `-fsrchFile` be run together.

Now you are finding all files starting /home, searching with fgrep for paypay, ebay, etc in all files. The -l says it will ONLY print the filename where a match is found. You can remove the -l and then you will see the output of what is found, prepended with the filename.

IHTH.